# What is the difference between graphql and sql

Tags: sql, controller, graphql, computer-science, webapi

What is the difference between graphql and sql.

If in graphql we select all the tables and all the columns of each table.

And sql in the endpoint serve we evaluate the query that does not have sql injected for prevent update or delete.

Performance is better whit graphql?

Really safety if it is extremely safe with graphql?

Answer (score -1):

GraphQL is not related to database, it's about the presentation layer, You can implement an API with that. for more information check the link bellow:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphQL

Comment: it's not 'about the presentation layer'

Comment: Yes it is, in the 3-tier architecture, the presentation layer is the interface, you can read more in the link below: https://www.jinfonet.com/resources/bi-defined/3-tier-architecture-complete-overview/

Comment: The presentation layer is the latest layer that user interacts with that. it can be as a web presentation layer or an API in a web service application.

Comment: graphql is a protocol, part of transport layer, can be used on BE only, between servers, w/o any FE/presentation

Comment: I ask about if change the protocol language graphql for simple slq o linq, so why need learn new sintax if qe have two sql and linq

Comment: it's not about alternative to sql ... it's about web protocol, alternative to REST, sql still can be used at server to talk to DB, different things, apples vs. oranges